# How to determine where a file is located in Mac

Tags: macos, mac, preview

I'll present my question in two parts, one specific and one more general.

Say I have a file open in Mac preview. I want to figure out the directory that the file is located in. How do I do this?

Furthermore, generally if I have an application running, is there a way to quickly figure out where that application is located, and what files (meaning where they are located) it is accessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Preview and most other OS X GUI apps that open documents in document windows, you can Command-click on the name of the file in the titlebar of the window to get a pop-up menu showing the path to the file.

To find where a running program is, Command-click on the app's icon in the Dock. All running GUI apps show up in the Dock. You can also use this for any app in the Dock, running or not.

To find what files a given process currently has open, you can use the `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app` utility. Select a process from the list of running processes, then choose `View > Inspect Process`, then click on the `Open Files and Ports` tab in the process inspector window.

If you're more Terminal-oriented, you can use the `lsof(8)` ("**l**i**s**t **o**pen **f**iles") command.